# Como alterar estado de objetos complexos no React?

Tags: javascript, react, jsx

tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
obj = {
  title: "obj1",
  tab: [{
     title: "titulo da tab 1",
     card: [{
        title: "card1",
        url: "url",
        image: "image"
     },
     { 
        title: "card2",
        url: "url",
        image: "image"
     }]

  },
  {
     title: "titulo da tab 2",
     card: [{
        title: "card3",
        url: "url",
        image: "image"
     },
     { 
        title: "card4",
        url: "url",
        image: "image"
     }]

  }
]
```

}

quando quero alterar o estado de uma variavel no react uso

```
setState({obj1: data})
```

quando quero alterar o estado de uma propriedade de um obj eu uso:

```
setState({obj1: {...this.state.obj1, title: "new title"} })
```

mas minha dificuldade é:

- Como alterar o titulo de um card no obj?
- Como alterar um titulo de tab no obj?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para estrutura largamente aninhadas eu acho preferível:

- Replicar o estado num objeto local, de forma a preservar o original.
- Alterar o que pretende nesse objeto
- Chamar o `setState` com esse novo estado

Exemplo:

```
const novoEstado = Object.assign({}, this.state);
novoEstado.obj1.tab[1].card[0].title = 'Novo titulo de um card';
novoEstado.obj1.tab[0].title = 'Novo titulo para o primeiro tab';
this.setState(novoEstado);
```

O [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) replica o estado que tem num novo objeto, preservando o original e seguindo o que a documentação indica de não alterar o estado diretamente.

Comment: é this.state mesmo ou é this.state.obj1 ? na linha 1

Comment: @JulioHenrique Foi lapso meu, não reparei que o estado tem como objeto raiz o `obj1`, mas a ideia é capturar o estado todo que é mais fácil. Vou ajustar